# Can I create any object of ArrayList in a Queue?

Tags: java, arraylist, queue

I am trying to do this:

```
Queue<Integer> Q = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

But My IDE gives me error.

Can any one please tell me, Why I can't create an object of `ArrayList` in a class of queue?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: incompatible type : ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted into Queue<Integer>.

Comment: That would seem to give you the exact answer to your question, no?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that because [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) does not `implement` [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). You could use a [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) instead:

```
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: But I think `LinkedList` does.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've included that hint.

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement BFS. So I need ArrayList and Queue both.

Comment: Why do you need an `ArrayList` for BFS? BTW: "How do I implement BFS" is a different question. Yours has been answered.

Comment: @MahmudulHasan An `ArrayList` does not `implements Queue` because `add()/remove()` from the start is `O(n)` and not `O(1)`. You are almost certainly doing something wrong if you want an `ArrayList` and a `Queue`.

Comment: Actually I am reading from a .txt file and ArrayList is to make an Adjacency list.

Answer (score 0):

Using of ArrayDeque instead of LinkedList makes it a little bit faster ...

```
Queue<Integer> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
```